# Returning rows that had no matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I've read and read and read but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I'm doing something like:

```
SELECT a
FROM t1
WHERE t1.b IN (<external list of values>)
```

There are other conditions of course but this is the jist of it.

My question is: is there a way to show which in the manually entered list of values didn't find a match? I've looked but I can't find and I'm going in circles.

Comment: Similar question, perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953163/

Answer (score 3):

Create a temp table with the external list of values, then you can do:

```
select item 
  from tmptable t
 where t.item not in ( select b from t1 )
```

If the list is short enough, you can do something like:

```
with t as (
select case when t.b1='FIRSTITEM' then 1 else 0 end firstfound
       case when t.b1='2NDITEM' then 1 else 0 end secondfound
       case when t.b1='3RDITEM' then 1 else 0 end thirdfound
       ...
  from t1 wher t1.b in 'LIST...'
)
select sum(firstfound), sum(secondfound), sum(thirdfound), ...
  from t
```

But with proper rights, I would use [Nicholas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520248/11621).

Comment: I was afraid of that, wanted to see if it was possible without that first before going ahead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To display which values in the list of values haven't found a match, as one of the approaches, you could create a nested table SQL(schema object) data type:

```
-- assuming that the values in the list 
-- are of number datatype

 create type T_NumList as table of number;
```

and use it as follows:

```
-- sample of data. generates numbers from 1 to 11 
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2     select level
  3       from dual
  4    connect by level <= 11
  5  )
  6  select s.column_value as without_match
  7    from table(t_NumList(1, 2, 15, 50, 23)) s -- here goes your list of values
  8    left join  t1 t
  9      on (s.column_value = t.col)
 10   where t.col is null
 11  ;
```

Result:

```
WITHOUT_MATCH
-------------
           15
           50
           23
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b6a/1)

Comment: This would work but still requires an object to be created outside of the query. It doesn't seem like I'm going to be able to avoid this regardless.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to convert "a externally provided" list into a table that can be used to do the comparison. One way is to use one of the (undocumented) system types to generate a table on the fly based on the values supplied:

```
with value_list (id) as (
   select column_value
   from table(sys.odcinumberlist (1, 2, 3))  -- this is the list of values
)
select l.id as missing_id
from value_list l
 left join t1 on t1.id = l.id
where t1.id is null;
```

Comment: Just to confirm - will doing it this way create a persistent table? Or will it only exist while the select query is resolving?

Comment: @user2723016: not, that does not create any database objects. The "table" with the IDs is generated "on-the-fly". It's essentially the same idea as with Gordon's answer (just without the ugly UNION ALL) and Nicholas' answer (just without creating an object type)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get what you have described, but they have requirements which exceed the statement of the problem.  From the minimal description provided, there's no way to have the SQL return the list of the manually-entered values that did not match.

For example, if it's possible to insert the manually-entered values into a separate table - let's call it `matchtbl`, with the column named `b` - then the following should do the job:

```
SELECT matchtbl.b
FROM matchtbl
WHERE matchtbl.b NOT IN (SELECT distinct b
                         FROM t1)
```

Of course, if the data is being processed by a programming language, it should be relatively easy to keep track of the set of values returned by the original query, by adding the `b` column to the output, and then perform the set difference.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the list in an `in` clause makes this hard.  If you can put the list in a table, then the following works:

```
with list as (
      select val1 as value from dual union all
      select val2 from dual union all
      . . .
      select valn
     )
select list.value, count(t1.b)
from list left outer join
     t1
     on t1.b = list.value
group by list.value;
```

Comment: I'm aware, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it without having to create a temporary table or similar before giving the SQL to the dbas.

Comment: @user2723016 . . . A CTE (the expression in the `with` statement) is not a temporary table.  In fact, you can write this without the `with`, just by putting it as a subquery.